# Adding Multiple Markers in real time google maps v2 android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I want to add markers when ever on camera change listener is called.

```
@Override
public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    double[] newValues = { position.target.latitude,
            position.target.longitude };
    new GetPlaces().execute(newValues);
}
```

AsyncTask Class which is used to get the center location of the map and get known places arround that location

```
private class GetPlaces extends AsyncTask<double[], Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(double[]... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        double[] vals = params[0];
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        try {
            locs = request.getPlaces(vals[0], vals[1]);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (result) {
                if (mMap != null) {
            if (locs.size() > 0) {


                    mMap.clear();

                    for (com.matsoltech.android.apps.easysavinghunter.Location loc : locs) {

                        Log.e("APPLICATION", "LOCATIONS FOUND ");
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(
                                        new LatLng(loc.getPoint()
                                                .getLatitude(), loc
                                                .getPoint().getLongitude()))
                                .title(loc.getName())
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Deal Found",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("APPLICATION", "MAP IS NULL");
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                    MainActivity.this,
                    "Oops..Something went wrong. Please check your connection and try again",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

In logcat the values are correct and data is being fetched properly .. the only problem is that my markers are not showing on the map. Please help!!

Comment: When you say values are correct do you also mean the Lat Lng values are correct? If not, maybe check if they're within the map or viewport.

Comment: @Andy took me a while to figure out that i was storing the lat value in lng and lng value in lat .. now it works perfectly!! thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that i wasn't putting the right values of Lat and Lng in the Point object. Now its working find!!